# Navigation using named routes, but so that one element (widget) is always on top

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I don't know how to make navigation so that one element (widget) always stays on top. And for it to work with named routes

[image]

As you can see in the video, I would like the bottom (purple) panel to always be on top. I use named routes and when I reload the page, another window pops up.And the url path disappears immediately.

Who can help and what information should be provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand you, but if you would like a screen, e.g. initial route, to always be visible when you navigate into another screen, then you can use PageRouteBuilder with a false opaque to achieve that;

```
  Navigator.of(ctx).push(
    PageRouteBuilder(
        opaque: false,
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
          return YourWidgetScreen();
        }),
  );
```